# Can a program (not PDA) have an associated token account?

Tags: token

I want to have a treasury of usdc for my program. Can a program have its own associated token account, and if so, how does it transfer usdc in and out of the treasury (in Rust)?

Thanks

Comment: why dont you want PDA as an associated token account. You can easily do whatever u specified by making the PDA as a token account and making the program as the authority.

Answer (score 5):

No. Programs have no way to sign for instructions that require authority, which includes many SPL Token operations. This use case is precisely why PDAs exist.

Answer (score 2):

Programs cannot have an ATA. For this use case, a pool token account can be initialized whose authority is set to a PDA signer. This way, the signer account can sign spl-token transfers out of the pool treasury.